# Using docValues to calculate facets on term vector of string field

Tags: solr

I have field in my SOLR schema which is defined like this:

```
<field name="text_t" type="text_t" indexed="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" />
```

This field is used for searching, but we also calculate facets over this field. Facets work fine, but use quite some resources, probably because the inverse index with the terms has to be (re-)inverted. Building the fieldValud-Cache after any commit is terrible slow and a serious performance problem. Reading the documentation I thought, that docValues should solve exactly this issue. But if I add `docValues="true"` to the field definition, I get the following error:

```
Field type text_t{class=org.apache.solr.schema.TextField,analyzer=org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain,args={class=solr.TextField, positionIncrementGap=100}} does not support doc values
```

Any hint how to get docValues working with a string field having a termVector? Or how to speed up faceting over such a field?

Comment: docValues don't work on TextField. You could try it on string field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a second field alongside the one you have trouble with that is of type `StrField`. Use that new field for faceting and do whatever you want with the other.

In general I would not recommend to use one field for too many purposes in Solr. If you want to search within a field, optimize it for that search purpose, if you want to facet by that field add a second field that is optimized for faceting. If this requires content to be duplicated in several fields, so be it.

If you [go by Solr's Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) a field that you want to use for faceting has the following specs

> Because faceting fields are often specified to serve two purposes, human-readable text and drill-down query value, they are frequently indexed differently from fields used for searching and sorting:
>
> - They are often not tokenized into separate words
> - They are often not mapped into lower case
> - Human-readable punctuation is often not removed (other than double-quotes)
> - There is often no need to store them, since stored values would look much like indexed values and the faceting mechanism is used for value retrieval.

Why do I write all this, because I can see that you have used a custom field type and I assume that this field type employs tokenization of some sort. This would explain why you are starting to see performance issues.